# How to re-use multiple .xib as a template to another .xib?

Tags: iphone, ios, xib

I want to re-use some **.xib** files as templates to the major views of my iOS app.
Can someone tell me if it's possible, in iOS, to achieve a "template-like" system such as: Header, Logo, Footer, and load them as separate **.xib** views to fill some placeholders inside another **.xib**?
And how can I do that?

Like this:

> In the same app, I have a Header.xib, Footer.xib, and I want to include them in my MainMenu.xib

Comment: Do you mean within one application, or are you looking for a template that can be used across applications?

Comment: In the same app, I have a Header.xib, Footer.xib, and I want to include them in my MainMenu.xib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse one xib files for multiple views just by using it in the `initWithNibName`call.

Then even if you have minor differences you can do them programmatically. I would recommend that you define one common `setupMyScreen` method which takes as a parameter the screenType you have and in a switch statement takes care of all the little modifications.

This way it is quite easy to maintain.

ps you might want to work on your acceptance level - otherwise one might not realy be inclined to provide answers to your questions...

Comment: I cannot have acceptance without posting good (and relative) doubts and answering questions, which in iOS wil be harder cause I started 2 weeks ago..

But, related to the question, how do I load multiple "partial" .xib's into the main's placeholders ?

Comment: you cannot load "partial" xibs or combine xibs. A viewController always gets instantiated with maximum 1 xib. It seems the easiest in your case is to solve it through shared code. You may put your header / footer in a view programmatically and just reuse these. Initially it might seem more complex and/or more work, however, once you have set it up it becomes really practical to use. ps Apple clearly states that one ViewController should control one screen. You may however create Objects that manage your footer and header as mentioned before...

Answer (score 1):

> It sounds like u want to use multiple views in a single view than
>   u must use UIView template into first one .

Comment: I tried to create an UIView loading a xib with an UIImageview, and then adding that to an UIView on the Main .xib. I just posted here because it didn't work. Do you know any tutorial?

Comment: this link might be helpful for u: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html

Comment: If you put all your views in one XIB, then when your application launches, it has to load the entire XIB into memory and construct all of the objects for all of the controls, and this takes a non-trivial amount of time.If instead you separate your views into separate XIBs, then your app will start up much faster. so sholud also try this link: http://www.iphoneapptuts.com/nib-files/how-to-use-multiple-nib-files/

Comment: I don't want to use complex views. Just one for the background, another for header/footer, this causes that much overhead? I just want to learn how you guys manage big projects in iOS. If I want to change the background image, should I change ALL the .xib? That unsustainable :(